# Downloading a file from resource server to browser (OAuth2)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, download

I'm implementing OAuth2 (100% spec compliant) in a project that I've been assigned to.

Let's say I have a file named 'file.txt' on the resource server.

The client wants to download the file. Suppose file downloads are done through another server, `dl.example.com` , because there may be **multiple resource servers**, and a common access point for downloads will be a neater approach. (?)

So if the client wants to download a file, and output it to the browser, what should be the preferred process?

If I take the following approach :

1) Client makes request to `dl.example.com?access_token=123123&fpath=file.txt`

2) `dl.example.com` makes request to the respective resource server

3) The resource server sends the file to `dl.example.com`

4) `dl.example.com` sends the file to the client

5) client outputs the file to the browser for download

there will be additional network I/O overhead.

Is this approach not the right way to go? How to 'big players' like Dropbox do it? I have checked Dropbox's url : `dl-web.dropbox.com/*whatever*` . Is Dropbox's approach totally different than the above one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not proxy the passing of the file resource via the `dl.example.com` server.

The access_token is the key here.  If the resource servers support OAuth2 themselves and have access to the store for the access_tokens you could respond with a status 303 redirect from the original request to the actual resource address in need:

```
Original Request:   https://dl.example.com?access_token=123123&fpath=file.txt
Response:   303 https://resource.server.com/path/file.txt?access_token=123123
```

You can flag Curl to follow redirects.  If you're developing an Client SDK to wrap access, this could all be invisible.

Comment: I see. Yes indeed, I'm developing a Client SDK. But then, would the download appear to be originating from the resource server, or will the url still be in the terms of `dl.example.com` ? (I don't quite understand HTTP Redirects completely)

Comment: @abhishek  if you're using CURL you set this option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`  Then it handles the redirection in the background.  You make the initial request and curl will pull the file from where you redirect.  I use 303 status code since the `dl.example.com?blahblah=blah` resource really isn't moving.  You return the 303 and the URL in the HTTP header response on the original dl.example.com server and CURL makes a second request in to the new resource location.  So there ends up being 2 requests, one for the resource address, then one for the final resource by curl

Comment: Yes I'm using curl. I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: yes I have already made all preparations for SSL. Thanks for the warning!! :)

Comment: yeah I'll do that once I test it. Thanks.

Comment: whoops, forgot to mark the answer as the correct one, it was a long time ago! It did indeed work. I used a common database cluster to store the tokens, and then authenticated the token directly on resource servers. `dl.example.com` only acted as a load balancer.